# how to calculate reverse modulus

Tags: c#, math, formula, reverse, modulus

now I have one formula:

```
int a = 53, x = 53, length = 62, result;
result = (a + x) % length;
```

but how to calculate reverse modulus to get the smallest "x" if I known result already

```
(53 + x) % 62 = 44
//how to get x
```

i mean what's the formula or logic to get x

Comment: lots of values of `x` will satisfy that equation. It would be fair to say the possibilities are infinite but, not within the bounds of `55` and `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Jodrell It was stated that he's looking for the smallest x. That limits it.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn oops, good point.

Comment: I guess the lowest is actually `-9`

Comment: I suppose the smallest **positive** "x" ...

Comment: @Jodrell: yes, that's my point...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
private int ReverseModulus(int div, int a, int remainder)
{
   if(remainder >= div)
      throw new ArgumentException("Remainder cannot be greater than or equal to divisor");
   if(a < remainder)
      return remainder - a;
   return div + remainder - a;
}
```

e.g. :

```
// (53 + x) % 62 = 44
var res = ReverseModulus(62,53,44); // res = 53

// (2 + x) % 8 = 3
var res = ReverseModulus(8,2,3); // res = 1
```

Comment: @Ivan Li: his `div + remainder - a` is my `B + C - A`. If mine doesn't work with other numbers, neither would this.

Comment: In that case, no answers work. I'm not trying to discredit your answer @digEmAll, I just feel a little shafted for having the same basic equation as you (12 mins before you), just without the obvious validation.

Comment: However, is it correct to consider the smallest positive x ? Otherwise the smallest in your example should be -9, not 53 ...

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: actually that's what my if condition handles. `(2 + 1) % 8 = 3` and `remainder - a` yields exactly 1... while the equal part of our codes gives 9...

Comment: You got me there, I didn't think about that. My edit now accounts for it all in one equation, but I do owe that to you.

Answer (score 5):

It may not be the X that was originally used in the modulus, but if you have

`(A + x) % B = C`

You can do

`(B + C - A) % B = x`

Comment: Nevermind, @digEmAll's answer points out where mine fails. Editted to account for that.

Comment: this of course is the first and good answer, but @digEmAll's straightforwardly solves my problem with if statement handling. but anyway, thanks, you guys help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`x = (44 - 53) % 62`  should work?

```
x = (44 - a) % length;
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
IEnumerable<int> ReverseModulo(
    int numeratorPart, int divisor, int modulus)
{
   for(int i = (divisor + modulus) - numeratorPart; 
       i += divisor; 
       i <= int.MaxValue)
   {
       yield return i;
   }
}
```

---

I'm now aware this answer is flawed because it does not gice the smallest but a `.First()` would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Who needs a computer? If 53 + x is congruent to 44, modulo 62, then we know that for integer k,

```
53 + x + 62*k = 44
```

Solving for x, we see that

```
x = 44 - 53 - 62*k = -9 - 62*k
```

Clearly the smallest solutions are -9 (when k=0) and 53 (when k=1).