# The inverse of modular multiplication in code

Tags: java, multiplication, modulus, inverse

I've read a lot about this subject, about Euclidean algorithm, and I have all references needed for this subject right here:

(Best source for my question) -> [Math Explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684550/how-to-reverse-modulo-of-a-multiplication)

Another great example -> [Math Explanation 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/calculating-the-modular-multiplicative-inverse-without-all-those-strange-looking)

Wiki -> [Extended Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Great answer for adding values -> [Add Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218534/how-to-calculate-reverse-modulus)

This is where I completely lost it -> [AFFINE CIPHERS](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter14.html)

However, out of all these sources, I'm still failing to understand how to implement it by code (or pseudo code), or at least find the way to write it.

So I'll write the basics, let's assume I have this formula:

> (x * key) % mod = result 
>   0 <= X <= mod
>  0 <= key <= mod
>  0 <= result<= mod

**key** and **mod** are **constants**. 
* means **multiplication** operation 
**%** means **remainder** operation (edited to clarify)
**x** and **result** are **dynamic**.

I want to create a formula that will give me x through code in Java.

The function that calculates *result* for me is:

```
private int MultModulus(int num, int key, int mod)
{
    return (num * key) % mod;
}
```

how can I find X? what should I write in order to calculate it? this is the point where I didn't understand, let's assume that my function signature would be:

```
private int InverseMultModulus(int result, int key, int mod)
{
    x = ...
    return x;
}
```

Comment: a small information. The `%` is the remainder operator and not a mathematical representation of the modulo calculation. That´s what, for example `Math#floorMod`, is there for.

Comment: oh, in that case, ill clarify that I meant the remainder operator.

Comment: The problem is not well-specified.  There are, in general, multiple possible `x` values.  Which do you want?

Comment: There isn't a unique answer. E.g. if `result == 1`, `mod == 2` and `key == 3`, `x` could be any positive odd number.

Comment: for the Add operation, there is only one solution, how's that for multiply there are multiple answers? the sources I brought shows that there's suppose to be only 1 correct answer. if I understood them correctly.

Comment: It's also possible that there is *no* answer.

Comment: I'll edit the question again, 0 <= X <= mod, 0 <= KEY <= mod

Comment: (X*5)%3=1 means X could be 2, 5, 8, etc.  (for positive numbers).  How did you want your answer to be provided to you?

Comment: There is no answer at all if `key` divides `mod` and `result` is not a multiple of `key`.  More generally, if `key` and `mod` are not relatively prime then there will be at least one value for `result` to which no `x` corresponds.  Otherwise, there may be more than one.

Comment: I assume it's all supposed to be done modulo `mod`. In which case you need to look at the `BigInteger` class. Assuming `result` and `key` don't have any prime factors in common with `mod` the answer (modulo `mod`) is `key.modInverse(mod).multiply(result)`.

Comment: @OriFrish, the math.stackexchange.com answer you presented gives a pretty clean explanation for how to perform the computation efficiently when there is in fact any answer at all.  The Wikipedia article describes how to compute the needed quantities.  What is preventing you from implementing the needed algorithm based on the information provided by those resources?

Comment: Well, to be honest with you, I'm sitting with my pen and paper, and just failing to understand how to convert it to code, I didn't fully understand the method they used in order to create the conversion.

Comment: @OriFrish, if the question boils down to "please implement the extended Euclidean algorithm for me" (or similar) then it is out of scope for SO.  If you have *specific* questions about how to implement the algorithm then we can address them (please post separate questions).  If you don't understand the algorithm in the first place, then you may find us receptive to *specific* questions about it, but most such questions would technically be out of scope, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as described in comments on @ergonaut's answer, you need to be able to solve this problem only for a relatively small number of original values `x`, and a relatively small value of `mod`, then one reasonable approach would be to build a decoding table in advance: perform the forward computation on every possible `x`, and record the starting `x` in an array, indexed on the `result`.  Then you can perform a simple array lookup to get an `x` for each result.  That will certainly outperform computing `x` separately for each value in a long enough sequence of values (i.e. the characters in a long enough enciphered message).  Of course, if you're doing this in the spirit of a Vignere cipher, i.e. with a multibyte key, then that will multiply the input length required for pre-computing a decoding table to be a win.

Do be aware, however, that using the function you describe to define a viable cipher depends on every valid input value yielding a distinct result.  As we already discussed, however, some combinations of `key` and `mod` afford duplicate results.  Moreover, if the space of possible result values is the same size as the space of possible input values, then you must choose a combination of `key` and `mod` that results in all possible `result` values being used, else you cannot avoid duplicates.

If you want to encipher bytes as bytes, and if you want to be able to handle general files, then the only possible `mod` is `256`.  If you choose a smaller one, then there has to be at least one pair of input bytes that map to the same cipherbyte.  On the other hand, if you choose a larger `mod` then the range of result values cannot be mapped 1:1 into the range of type `byte`.  You must furthermore be certain to choose `key`s that are relatively prime with 256, but that's easy: since 256 is a power of 2, any odd key will do.  As long as you choose such a key, no two input values in any range of 256 consecutive integers will map to the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you suggest any other approach which I can create this cipher? maybe something that not including any modulu operation.

I did solve it by encrypting every char to a 4-bytes size data. so when I read back, I'm sure my encrypted file is based of 4bytes data that I can read, and just decrypt back. however, it makes every file 4 times bigger, which is not a good conversion.

Comment: @OriFrish, It is possible to implement a variants of Vignere cipher for "alphabets" of any size.  In particular you can implement it for a 256-character alphabet.  That ordinarily does involve computing remainders, but it's `(x + key) % size` rather than `(x * key) % size`.  It is much easier to decipher, given a known key.  Perhaps that will suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Run through the MultModulus, but iterate with X in [0, mod] to return the answer and store them in an array.

```
for (int i=0;i<mod;i++){
    if (MultModulus(i, key, mod) == result){
       // store answer in array
    }
}

return array;
```

Comment: Your solution works, however, it works partly, since from some reason some ascii letters like " and ' are simply not being written back, it also works in the same way for the add-operation solution that I brought, do you have any idea why's that?

Comment: @OriFrish, you posed a numeric problem.  What do ASCII characters have to do with it?

Comment: You're right, basically, I write a small conversion algorithm for "encrypting" files, since it's not using any real encrypting algorithms out there. now, the algo, replaces any ascii letter in file with a key, that could be added to the char, or multiplyed with it. and I've done it with writing a 4-bytes (for every char) encrypted file, but I wanna try to do it with 1 byte, and the modulus function, to save space.

Comment: Not sure about the ascii, but you can use this technique anywhere you don't want to use/derive the inverse calculation by using the forward calculation, and you have a small finite set of inputs it could be.  eg. If a^b (mod c) was your formula, and you didn't want to deal with roots/logarithms, and you knew lower<a<upper, for a small range, I would use this approach.